# tableView data gets reloaded every time I scroll it

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll

So every time I scroll my tableView it reloads data which I find ridiculous since it makes no sense to reload data as it hasn't been changed.
So I setup my tableView as follows:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.numberOfElements
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 6
}
```

My cells are really custom and they require spacing between them. I couldn't add an extra View to my cell to fake that spacing because I have corner radius and it just ruins it. So I had to make each row = a section and set the spacing as a section height.

My cell has a dynamic height and can change it's height when I click "more" button, so the cell extends a little.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        if self.isCellSelectedAt[indexPath.section] {
            return self.fullCellHeight
        } else {
            return self.shortCellHeight
        }
    } else {
        return 148
    }
}
```

And here's how I setup my cell:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = UITableViewCell()

    if self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String.className(CurrentDocCell.self)) as! CurrentDocCell
        (cell as! CurrentDocCell).delegate = self
        (cell as! CurrentDocCell).ID = indexPath.section
    } else {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String.className(PromissoryDocCell.self)) as! PromissoryDocCell
    }

    return cell
}
```

So I have a segmentedControl by switching which I can present either one cell of a certain height or the other one which is expandable.

In my viewDidLoad I have only these settings for tableView:

```
    self.tableView.registerCellNib(CurrentDocCell.self)
    self.tableView.registerCellNib(PromissoryDocCell.self)
```

And to expand the cell I have this delegate method:

```
func showDetails(at ID: Int) {
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.isCellSelectedAt[ID] = !self.isCellSelectedAt[ID]
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

I set a breakpoint at cellForRowAt tableView method and it indeed gets called every time I scroll my tableView.
Any ideas? I feel like doing another approach to make cell spacing might fix this issue.

Comment: do not add a breakpoint but add logging that outputs the indexpath of the cell reloaded. If a cell that is off-screen enters the screen the `cellForRowAt` method is rightfully called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A UITableView only loads that part of its datasource which gets currently displayed. This dramatically increases the performance of the tableview, especially if the datasource contains thousands of records.

So it is the normal behaviour to reload the needed parts of the datasource when you scroll.